# How determine HTML input text is too long to be displayed entirely?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, input

How to detect if user provided text which is longer than HTML `<input>` is able to display entirely?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the `maxlength` attribute, which can be set like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="LENGTH HERE">
```

As far as the maximum length that you are using, it depends on the size of the `input` element. I would recommend guessing and checking until you find a value that works best for your use case.

Comment: I'm looking for visual property to detect overflows. `maxlength` is not it. But thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

first retrieve your `input` by `querySelector`

```
const sample=document.querySelector("specificInput")
```

then access the text inside it by `value` property

```
const text=sample.value;
```

if you want to check width of each word use `split()` method to seprate your words from each other and store it in an array.

```
const wordArray=text.split(" ");
```

(inside split() you should use space because in that case only retrieves the words)

but if you want the whole text, you can just skip `split()` section.

then use `measureText().width` to check the width of the text or words(if you want to check the width of the words, because they are stored inside an array, you should iterate over array to check their widths)

and for the end, use an `if` condition to check if the width of the word or text is larger than the specific area or not, if the width of the text or word was more than the width of the specific area **possibly** you have overflow.

( when I say **"possibly"** it is  because I don't know what you are designing for example in a simple `div` container if the text is larger than the container, text overflow wouldn't happen and text eventually wraps but if the word is bigger than the container, it overflows).

Comment: Uhm, the spec says `measureText()`is only for canvas elements available. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: if you are not comfortable with this approach use `clientWidth` property to calculate width of the text or word.@Reporter